# Variance of stochastic integrals

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, variance

I have 2 stochastic integrals :

$ I(T):= \int_0^T W(t)^2 \, d(t)$

$ J(T):= \int_0^T W(t)^2 \, dW(t)$

As $W(t)$ is the standard wiener process.

I need to show $Var(I(T))= \frac{T^4}{3}$ and $Var(J(T))=T^3$

I know I need to use Ito Isometry but I cant get the results I need to prove.
Please Help!

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? In order to calculate the variance you need the expectation value of the integrals... any ideas on that?

Comment: $\text{var} (J(T))  = \mathbb{E}((J(T))^2) = \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int_0^T W(t)^2 \, dW(t) \right)^2 \right]= \left[ \left( \int_0^T\mathbb{E}( W(t)^2) \, d(t) \right)^2 \right]=\left[ \left( \int_0^T\mathbb{E}( W(t)^4) \, d(t) \right) \right]=\left[ \left( \int_0^T3t^2 \, d(t) \right) \right]=T^3$

Comment: Is it OK? for $Var(I(T))$ I have no clue...

Comment: If you know why $\mathbb{E}(J(T))=0$, then this is correct.